# Drop down list con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Buenos dias, estoy intentando sacar los datos en un combo y no se si algo me falla, debe de mostrarme las opciones fijas.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', 'root', '');
$sql = "SELECT acro_subcategoria FROM tipodocumentos";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$tipodocumentos = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Y este seria el select

```
<select>
<?php foreach ($tipodocumentos as $acro_subcategoria): ?>
<option value="<?= $acro_subcategoria['acro_subcategoria']; ?>"></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: ¿qué errores te da? ¿cómo podemos ayudarte? Intenta dar un [mcve]

Comment: Qué esperas obtener? Qué estás obteniendo actualmente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salvo error por mi parte tienes la apertura de php mal en la siguiente línea:

Prueba cambiando

```
<option value="<?= $acro_subcategoria['acro_subcategoria']; ?>"></option>
```

por

```
<option value="<?php $acro_subcategoria['acro_subcategoria']; ?>"></option>
```

Comment: Vale perfect era eso, pero una cosa que me resutla rara es la siguiente, cuando quiero ingresar datos el cuadro me sale vacio:

http://imgur.com/a/r5zii

Pero si quiero editarlo solo me da la opcion de esa tantas veces se supone que los datos deberian de ser diferentes:

http://imgur.com/a/I8Mb3

Comment: @AlbertoCeperodeAndrés esta otra cuestión necesitará que abras una nueva pregunta, dado que esta ha quedado resuelta. Te ruego por favor que me des la respuesta como validada si te ha servido de ayuda, así en futuras consultas quien entre sabrá que la misma ha sido resuelta. Gracias.

Comment: listo, gracia spor tu ayuda!!.

Comment: ¿No le faltaría un `echo` a la solución que sugieres?

Comment: Aparte, esa apertura de PHP no está mal, es válida y bastante común. El problema es que no la tendrá activada en el servidor (que será < 5.4)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Desconocía que se podía abrir de esa forma. ¿Me permites que modifique la respuesta incluyendo el `echo`?

Comment: Es tu propia respuesta, puedes editarla y añadir/borrar lo que quieras sin permiso de nadie :)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro cierto, pero no he sido yo quien ha detectado que falta la instrucción `echo` y no me gusta atribuirme méritos de nadie :)